# Understanding preloading of picture element's images via link tag

Tags: html, image

I am testing with this simple web page.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" >
   <head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <title>preload picture element</title>
      <link 
         rel="preload"
         as="image"
         type="image/webp"  
         imagesrcset="https://placehold.co/750x375 750w, https://placehold.co/860x430 860w"
         imagesizes="100vw"
         media="(max-width: 47.9375em)"
         >
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
      <style>
         body {
            margin: 0;
         }
         img {
            max-inline-size: 100%;
            block-size: auto;
         }
      </style>
   </head>
   <body>
      <picture>
         <source srcset="https://placehold.co/750x375 750w, https://placehold.co/860x430 860w" sizes="100vw">
         <img src="https://placehold.co/750x375" width="750" height="375" alt="">
      </picture>
   </body>
</html>
```

When viewing this in Chrome with a responsive viewport of 375x500 and DPR: 2.0, the 750px wide image is (pre)loaded as expected. When I change DPR to 3 and reload, the 860px wide image is (pre)loaded as expected.

**"Error situation"**: When I then switch back to DPR of 2, the 750px version is preloaded, but the picture element loads the 860px version and displays it.

I can not make any sense of this behaviour, do you?